# How to enable horizontal auto scrolling of big images via jCarousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jcarousel

I'm using jCaousel 0.3.3, jQuery 1.9.1. I'm seeing no errors, but slides do not change (move).

HTML code:

```
<div class="views-field jcarousel-wrapper">
  <div class="field-content jcarousel">
    <ul>
      <li class="first"><img width="1140" height="380" src="http://jonevans.photography/galleries/landscape/photos/jme_20141101_wilton_0001.jpg" typeof="foaf:Image"></li>
      <li><img width="1140" height="380" src="http://www.moargut.com/%28cms%29/media/resize/size=1140x380,scale=crop/1032683" typeof="foaf:Image"></li>
      <li class="last"><img width="1140" height="380" src="http://www.girosole.com/assets/images/tourpics/tourpic-guht1.jpg" typeof="foaf:Image"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.jcarousel').jcarouselAutoscroll();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/12Lst30m/3/

Could someone give me any advice? What I am doing wrong?